# Navigate to a random website using the TWebBrowser Component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, random, web, delphi-xe6

I wish to navigate to a random website in the `TWebBrowser` component. There are millions of websites online, but how do I select a random website and navigate to it in the webbrowser.

I'm planning to make an application which is very basic. One of the buttons is a random website button which takes the user to a random website.

I'm using Delphi XE6. How do I do this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? The harder part is selecting a random website. Is that what you are stuck on? In which case please focus the question on that, and you ideas and thoughts on what "random" means here.

Comment: -1 for really bad question.  It's two questions really.  One to browse to a given URL.  The other to generate "random" URL strings, presumably to valid destination, probably from a list of such destinations.  Don't ask us to solve both in the same question.  Break it up into two, if you really can't figure out either one on your own.

Comment: Lol, I know how to navigate. I would like to know how to navigate to a random website. I know how to browse to URL's and stuff.

Comment: @Computer If you know that, why are you asking how to navigate? Please fix that. Then your question is how to come up with a random site. You need to decide what that means.

Comment: because I don't know how to navigate to a random website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 5 years I have finally decided to answer my own question properly. Here is a function I wrote to navigate to a random website on the internet:

```
procedure RandomWebsite;
const
  A = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm';
var
  i: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := 1 to random(20) do
    s := s + A[random(A.Length)];
  s := s + '.com';

  try
    IdIcmpClient1.Host := s;
    IdIcmpClient1.Ping();
    Webbrowser1.Navigate(s);
  except
    RandomWebsite;
  end;
end;
```

I'm using the `TIdIcmpClient` component from INDY to ping the host and see if the website exists. If the website exists, then I navigate to it. If it doesn't exist, then I try a different host url.

My written procedure is very simple. You can ofcourse modify it to fit your needs and make it even more "random". My example only goes to .com domains and with letters in it.

This example should be enough however for most people looking for this solution on how to navigate to a random website using Delphi TWebBrowser.

Comment: In 99% of cases the ping will go to a **non-existing URL**, that is not 'to a website'. Together with the recursive call in the exception handler you'll probably run into stack overflow errors. Relying on an exception and then bluntly retrying for a 1:100 hit is just *bad code*.

Comment: @JanDoggen Haha yeah. This definitely isn't the best way to do it. It's just a simple example on how it could possibly be done. You're welcome to improve the code if you have a better way. I might most likely come back to this answer again in a few months or so when I have time to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

You need a source of websites to pick from. Either you make a list yourself or you use one of the [websites that make you jump to a random web site](https://www.google.com/search?q=random+website), like [The Useless Web](http://www.theuselessweb.com/) (which as it says is a selection of *useless* sites) or the [Random Website Machine](http://www.whatsmyip.org/random-website-machine/) at `WhatsMyIp.com`.

If you can disect the code of the intermediate site you can use it yourself, otherwise you have to load it and execute a button click.

I also tried [Randomwebsite](http://www.randomwebsite.com/) but if fails to load. This shows the drawback of this approach: you rely on the availability of the intermediate site.
But if you're using a list of your own, you'll also have to detect websites that are gone, and present a new one.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not try it myself, but I think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Googles "I'm feeling lucky" link:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate('http://www.google.com/search?q=TEST&btnI');
```

This is actually a search, so change the *TEST* search string with any value you like: *book*, *kitten*, *fluffy+animals*,...

Comment: Be care that if page has an `onunload`, it might require user confirmation. And programmer should also consider to block unexpected some popups, otherwise your application will out of your control after couple of hours free running.

Comment: Ok thanks and if I want to search to any website from all categories and everything? There shouldn't be anything specific.